# How does one find all objects that contain “blah” in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, search-engine

I have been using **wildcard** like so: `*blah*` But, the docs state that you shouldn’t start out a wildcard value with `*` because it can increase iterations required and slow down search performance.

Also, there is no indication in the docs as to whether or not wildcard is intended to be case-insensitive. I noticed that when I searched for a lowercase “a” I got back everything that had both “a” or “A”, but when I searched for a capital “A”, so literally `*A*`, I got back no results at all.

I want this specific search to behave exactly like e.g., Django’s ORM would behave if I used `filter(title__icontains=‘blah’)`, including **case-insensitivity**. So, if I say `get me all records that contain the word ‘the’ in the title`, I would expect anything with “the” (case-insensitive) in the title to be returned.

Comment: Can you clarify with some examples of terms that you would want to do wildcard searches on?  For example, if you're doing search-as-you-type suggestions, then maybe a prefix query is what you're looking for.

Comment: @dmbaughman It’s not for real time searching while typing or suggestions, just for ordinary search. We have all kinds of search operators that we allow our users to use, but if they don’t use any operator at all then we just do a plain old fashion look up for “any object with the title containing this string”. An example might be a street name (“Belvedere”), a part of a street name, a series of digits, or even a two letter sequence. For this kind of search that isn’t using operators in our system we just basically want it to be as dumb as possible, not to be clever with replacements, etc.

Comment: @dmbaughman For example, “belvedere” might match a business with the name “Belvedere pizza”, or a residence with the address “123 Belvedere St.”. It needs to always be case insensitive, and the string that the user enters can appear anywhere in the title. It can’t even appear in the middle of a word. So, for instance, I would want “elved” to match an object where “Belvedere” is in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you would get around the cautionary approach of using the wildcard query, so here's what that would look like, in case you were just having trouble with the syntax:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "title": {
        "value": "*elved*",
        "boost": 1.0,
        "rewrite": "constant_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I just tested this type of query on my own search index, and searching for `*oam*` correctly matched "foaming" in product titles.

---

And as for the **case-insensitivity**, that should be handled out-of-the-box, as long as you're using one of the built-in analyzers (e.g. [Standard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) or [English](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer)).  But if you're using a custom analyzer, then you'll just need to make sure to include the `lowercase` filter, along with whatever other filters you want to run the terms through.

```
PUT index_name
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're not specifying an analyzer in your field mapping, then I believe it uses `standard` by default, which includes lowercase filtering.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, is it your opinion that this wild card performance is a serious issue (like there will be fires in production) or perhaps just that it’s not as optimal as using something more specific? It just seems so strange to me that a search engine would warn against what seems like basically the most obvious use… searching for a string of text within a field. I could just use term or something like that, but then it would filter out stop words; or, is there a way to get around that?

Comment: You'd be better off asking about performance on the official Elastic forums ([discuss.elastic.co](https://discuss.elastic.co/)).  My gut feeling is that if your fields aren't too long (e.g. addresses or names of people or products), then it's probably not going to have a noticeable impact on performance.  If you find that performance is seriously impacted by using a two-way wildcard, another approach you could use is fuzziness or a fuzzy query, to allow for partial matches as well as handling typos.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it there and keep the fuzzy option in mind as well.